# how to deal with padded 0 during feedforward process

Tags: tensorflow, mask, feed-forward

Assume I have a lists of inputs of different sizes, for example, some are of the shape[10,9,5] some are [7,6,5], I have to pad 0s to feed them into tensor flow with the same size, say [10,9,5], I need to do matrix multiplication and add the biases during the forward process which will introduce numbers in the padded 0 positions. So I have to create a mask matrix by myself to mask them? Or is there an easier way from tensorflow? Thanks!

BTW, I'm not feeding sequences nor using rnn. so I cannot use dynamic rnn

Comment: What is your final goal? Are you worried that zeros will hurt the NN performance?

Comment: The NN is used to do a regression problem. Because there're values appearing in those padded 0 positions, this will definitely influence the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use [attention mechanism](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473) to convert the variable-length inputs to some fixed length tensor before you feed them into a feed forward network.